# How to make a DateTimeExpression feature a transient in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am searching one thing with the date like what is happening tomorrow and I am getting result for tomorrow but again if I am saying what is happening, then too it is taking tomorrow's date.

My training for tomorrow is time.DateTimeExpression and my input is dateTimeExpression and type is time.DateTimeExspression. I have read the document about making a concept transient but how to make this time as transient?

based on the last comment, I am adding the training pics

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need all attributes of DateTimeExpression, you don't have to use it. Your input could be of type DateTime or Date too.

But if you have to use DateTimeExpression as input, you can extend the type and add transient feature to it

```
structure (MyDateTimeExpression) {
  role-of(viv.time.DateTimeExpression)
  features {
    transient
  }
}
```

Now, when you use MyDateTimeExpression, it will be transient.

Comment: If I am defining this structure and setting input type of this structure, then what will be value for Tomorrow or Next Week in training? because If I am setting value for Tomorrow to `MyDateTimeExpression` then it is showing me illegal plan. same 
 is happening when i am assigning it to `time.DateTimeExpression`.

Comment: My structure is same as you have given, just this change `structure (Date)` and input is dateTimeExpression and type is `Date`

Comment: Make sure that your tags have both the role (MyDateTimeExpression) and value (DateTimeExpression).

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example capsule that may help. [Here](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018778253) is an article on the Bixby Developer Community Forum which provides the example as an attachment along with a short description.

Comment: I am not authorised to access this page... this is saying

Comment: I apologize for that. You should be able to access it now.

Comment: Absolutely what i wanted.. thank you so much... I ahave posted other questions as well.. please answer